How Can I Fix "'setSigningKey(java. security. Key)' is deprecated "
I Java Spring Boot App, I Just Update Maven Libraries:
(jjwt-api (0.12.6)) from (jjwt-api (0.11.0))
And This My Old Code For Claims:
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;

Claims claims = Jwts
    .parserBuilder()                // Initializes JWT Parser Builder
    .setSigningKey(encryptionKey()) // Sets The Encryption Key For Parsing
    .build()                        // Builds The JWT Parser
    .parseClaimsJws(token)          // Parses The Token To Retrieve Claims
    .getBody();                     // Retrieves The Claims Body

First Error "Cannot resolve method 'parserBuilder' in 'Jwts'";
If Fix It By Replace parserBuilder() With parser()
After Changed It's Show Notifications:

'setSigningKey(java. security. Key)' is deprecated
'parseClaimsJws(java. lang. CharSequence)' is deprecated
'getBody()' is deprecated

How Can I Fix This?

The new syntax would be:
Jwts.parser()
    .verifyWith(encryptionKey())
    .build()
    .parseSignedClaims(jwt)
    .getPayload();

